# Showcaseview not displaying action bar items

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, showcaseview

So in my project I am using a showcaseview to create a tutorial for the user. When I point the ShowcaseView to any action bar id, the result is this:
[image]

My question is is it possible to have the showcaseview target the specific items in the action bar rather than just a general overview like the one shown above. The code is being run in the overridden onCreateOptionsMenu method and is in the context of an activity. Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
actionBarViews = new ShowcaseViews(activity);
    ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions co = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
    co.hideOnClickOutside = true;
actionBarViews.addView(new ItemViewProperties(R.id.sendmessage,
            R.string.send_title, R.string.send_tutorial,
            ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_ITEM, 0, co));
actionBarViews.addView(new ItemViewProperties(R.id.tutorial_menu,
            R.string.tutorial_title, R.string.tutorial_tutorial,
            ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_OVERFLOW, 0, co));

    actionBarViews.show();
```

If it is impossible to currently target actionbaritems,  is there another way to go about implementing a tutorial.

Comment: Did you get this working?  I am trying to do this with the support library.

Comment: I ended up using action bar sherlock instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to use [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)? It supports old compatibility and has quite a lot of available examples.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would have thought that the library would have been compatible with the stock action bar but it seems that I will have better luck with ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little late, but this may be useful for other users who find this thread. I used the following code to highlight my action button with ShowCaseView

```
        //for action button with id "ACTION_BUTTON_ID"

        ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions co = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
        co.showcaseId = ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_ITEM;
        co.hideOnClickOutside = true;
        ActionItemTarget target = new ActionItemTarget(this.getActivity(),R.id.ACTION_BUTTON_ID);
        final ShowcaseView sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(target,getActivity(),R.string.instruction_title_text,R.string.instruction_details_text);
        sv.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

use it like this

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(activity)
       // .withMaterialShowcase()
     //  .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme3)
        .setTarget(Target.NONE)
        .setOnClickListener(this)
        //.withMaterialShowcase()
        .blockAllTouches()
        .useDecorViewAsParent() //this is the difference
        .build();
```

then target your view in action bar